# outstandingFileTransfers property in the WCSession contains even successfully transferred files

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos, watchos-3

I am transferring a few files from an Apple Watch (Watch OS 3) App to the counterpart iOS App (iOS 10). The file gets transferred to the iOS App successfully, but still shows up in the `outstandingFileTransfers` property on the WatchApp Extension. Can someone tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: No, it should disappear. Do you get the callback on the sending side that the transfer was successful?

Comment: I agree. Yes, i do. `outstandingFileTransfers` property contains the file for which the delegate method got called. It's weird. Although all's well when you relaunch the app until it starts happening again.

Comment: sounds worthy of a bug report to Apple :)

Comment: You're probably right. I'll get onto that.

Comment: For what it's worth I'm still having this same problem.

Comment: @Erik does it happen with iOS 11 and watchOS 4?

Comment: @VishalV.Shekkar I'm not certain. The project I'm working on specifies that watchOS 3 be used so I haven't tested on 4.